# UK visa refusal for insufficient funds

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I had applied for standard tourist visa from India. I booked my flight ticket from Mumbai to London and return. I had also stated my itinerary during my stay in London. My UK visa got refused saying insufficient financial security under V4.3 (c). My father was sponsoring my trip. His ITR was low and did not meet their expectation.

Can I apply for the same visa immediately, by adding another sponsor, my uncle instead of my father?. My uncle has good ITR and bank statement. Will they consider my application since I have added a new sponsor?

How do I go about it?

Comment: Adding sponsors increases the difficulty you will have in demonstrating that you qualify.  There is some discussion about this in https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e

Comment: Is your Uncle actually going to pay for your trip?

Answer (score 2):

No, forget about doing that. Shopping sponsors will only lead to another refusal. It smacks of a lack of genuineness, basically looking for anything just to satisfy the requirements. Read about similar cases here on travelexchange.

Comment: "Read about similar cases here" ... Where?

Comment: How long should someone wait before re-applying with a different sponsor?

Comment: @Michael On travelexchange. Use the search function.

Comment: That really wasn't clear. Perhaps edit your answer to clarify? Click here to edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well​ my mother had a similar refusal in first time. Her problem was that​ she only mentioned the sponsor, but didn't attach any supporting documents for it.
She re-applied with all the bank account statements, credit card statements, income details of sponsor etc and her visa was approved this time. 
I suggest you to try again with proper documentation.

Also attach any ID like your student ID card etc which will give them confidence that you will return.

Comment: What was the number of days between both applications?

Comment: A student card is probably a bad idea, since they're easily forged. The UK Visas and Immigration [guidelines](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/549692/Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_English_version.pdf) talk about using a letter from your college on their headed note paper to confirm that you're a student.

Comment: @camden_kid  21 days, to be exact.